# Что там с imgur?

Tags: поддержка, imgur

Весь день сомнительно работает imgur. То картинки с него не открываются, то вообще загрузить на него не выходит. И всё жутко мееееедленно...

> Сбой при загрузке изображения; imgur.com отклонил запрос | Закрыть

[image: скриншот]

[image: скриншот 500]

Comment: Хм.. Граватар туда же?

Comment: Сегодня приходилось некоторые страницы с картинками форсированно обновлять минуя кеш. Потом вроде ожило.

Comment: @alexolut, ошибки вроде не кэшируются...

Comment: я видел пустые квадратики вместо некоторых картинок. Обычный F5 не помогал.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291609/339911

Comment: Вчера долго не мог залить на imgur изображение ...

Comment: @alexolut, по-прежнему глючит.

Comment: @Qwertiy да. Недавно о5 был тупняк какой-то. Видимо не долечили.